# Speeding up Gather / DatePlus combination

Tags: date-and-time, gathering

I am working on a project that involves identifying runs of dates that fall within five business days of each other. Given a list of dates in `inDates`, the following code does what I want:

```
Gather[inDates, DatePlus[#1, {5, "BusinessDay"}] > #2 &]
```

For input longer than a few dates, though, it's insanely slow. Consider the following 139-member input:

```
inDates={DateObject[{2015, 7, 31}], DateObject[{2015, 11, 4}], DateObject[{2016, 1, 8}], DateObject[{2016, 6, 17}], DateObject[{2016, 11, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 15}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 16}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 22}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 23}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 27}], DateObject[{2017, 2, 28}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 1}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 2}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 3}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 6}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 7}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 8}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 9}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 10}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 13}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 14}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 15}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 16}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 20}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 22}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 23}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 27}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 28}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 29}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 30}], DateObject[{2017, 3, 31}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 3}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 4}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 5}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 6}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 7}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 10}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 11}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 12}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 13}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 18}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 19}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 20}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 25}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 26}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 27}], DateObject[{2017, 4, 28}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 1}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 2}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 3}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 4}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 5}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 8}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 9}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 10}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 11}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 12}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 15}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 16}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 18}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 19}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 22}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 23}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 25}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 26}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 30}], DateObject[{2017, 5, 31}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 1}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 2}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 5}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 6}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 7}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 8}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 9}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 12}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 13}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 14}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 15}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 16}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 19}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 20}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 22}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 23}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 26}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 27}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 28}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 29}], DateObject[{2017, 6, 30}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 3}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 5}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 6}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 7}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 10}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 11}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 12}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 13}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 14}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 18}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 19}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 20}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 25}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 26}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 27}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 28}], DateObject[{2017, 7, 31}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 1}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 2}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 3}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 4}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 7}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 8}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 9}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 10}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 11}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 14}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 15}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 16}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 17}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 18}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 21}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 22}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 23}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 24}], DateObject[{2017, 8, 25}]};
```

On my desktop machine, this takes almost two minutes to process, and I have thousands of such inputs to deal with so it's not acceptable. I can save 97% of my run time by ditching the BusinessDay requirement and instead running

```
Gather[inDates, DatePlus[#1, 5] > #2 &]
```

But this really isn't what I want. Is there some way to radically speed up this operation while preserving the BusinessDay math?

Comment: You could sort the dates and use `Split` instead of `Gather`. This way only neighbouring list elements need to be compared, so you get O(1) complexity instead of O(2).  There's a fundamental problem with what you're doing though: "within 5 business days of each other" is not an equivalence relation (it's not transitive) ...

Comment: @Szabolcs For those of us with small minds, explain in more detail what the fundamental problem is?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something ... but if the question were to break a list of numbers into sets so that numbers are within a distance of two, then we can do `{1,2,3,7,8,9}` -> `{{1,2,3}, {7,8,9}}`. That's fine. But what if we have `{1,2,3,4,5}`?  `1, 3` are within a distance of 2 and so are `3, 5`. But `1, 5` aren't. So how do we break up the list?

Comment: The documentation of `Gather` implies that it expects an equivalence relation as its second argument (i.e. an equality test that does not lead to contradiction like above: `a==`b` and `b==c` but `a!=c`).  I would not trust it when passing it a comparison that is not an equivalence relation.  Of course in practical situations it often makes sense to work with such flawed relations—but you need to be aware of potential problems.  Technically even `==` isn't an equivalence relation in Mathematica because it works with tolerances.

Comment: @Szabolcs If I have a max allowable gap of 1, {1,2,3,4,5} (which has no gaps) and {1,2,4,5} (which has a gap of 1) remain unchanged, but {1,4,5} (which has a gap of 2) gets broken into {1} and {4,5}.

Comment: It sounds like you are relying on ordering to get a well defined result. You are treating `{1,2,3,4,5}` differently from `{3,2,1,5,4}`: you always order the lists.  In this case I suggest `Split` instead of `Gather`

Comment: @Szabolcs you are correct that I am relying on ordering. Let me try `Split` and I will report back.

Comment: @Szabolcs You win. `Gather` with `BusinessDays` → 114 seconds. `Split` with BusinessDays → 6 seconds. `Split` with ordinary days → 0.2 seconds. I appreciate you don't need the stackexchange points, but if you put this suggestion as an answer I will accept it, allowing others to see the problem has been solved.